# static_cast class to another class?

Tags: c++

I want to convert a class to another class. I'm trying to use static_cas which almost always work for me, why doesn't it work in the following?

```
struct Mouse
{
    Mouse() {}
    // .......
};

struct Mice
{
    Mice() {}
    // .........
};

int main()
{
    Mouse mouse;
    Mice mice = static_cast<Mice>(mouse);
}
```

Comment: Just because "mice" is plural of "mouse" it does not mean these classes are related. There is no conversion that allows converting a mouse into mice - it would be magic, really...

Comment: You basically need to understand what `static_cast` does. See a short description of how it works [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used).

Answer (score 3):

You can only cast an instance of Mouse into Mice if Mice has a constructor accepting Mouse, or Mouse has an `operator Mice` (latter is not particularly recommended).

Answer (score 1):

Because not only is `mouse` not an instance of `Mice`, but it can't possibly be.

```
struct SomeBase
{
  //...
};
struct SomeDerived : SomeBase
{
  //...
};
struct Unrelated
{
  //...
};

SomeBase * b;
SomeDerived * d;
Unrelated * r;

//....

b = static_cast<SomeBase *>(d); //allowed, safe
d = static_cast<SomeDerived *>(b); //allowed, unsafe
r = static_cast<Unrelated *>(d); //not allowed, what is it even meant to do?
```

Comment: The second cast isn't allowed either (and the first cast slices the object).

Comment: Right you are @UncleBens I was thinking of pointers to the types in question rather than the types. This is what happens when you don't code C++ for a bit :)

Comment: LOL. And the third one was allowed because of a typo. Thanks for the edit, @UncleBens

Comment: I think the second is allowed. But really unsafe.